# How do you represent either / or within a use case diagram?

Tags: class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I am making a use case diagram for a school and was wondering how I can show a degree course is either full time or part time and then each degree contains 1 to 10 courses.

Thanks!

Comment: `I am making a use case diagram ` : can you show what you already did ?

Answer (score 3):

The rules you are giving in your question are not captured in the *use case model*, but in the *domain model*. The description of a use case is influenced by the domain model. Like for example a use case `enroll for term` will describe steps where the user enters one or more courses. For a domain model you would create a class diagram.